# iOSDropDown not recognizing taps

Tags: ios, swift, dropdown

I am new to ios so i used a library for dropdown called **IOSDropDown** by By Jishnu Raj T in Swift. It's available on [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSDropDown) and [Github](https://github.com/jriosdev/iOSDropDown). I have added it successfully.

I have a textview under this dropdown and in the documentation it's listed

> If you are using Multiple Drop Downs in a Single ViewController, Must
>   Kept reverse order on StoryBoard or addSubview()  to avoid Overlaying

So I reversed the order the dropdown is visible on top of its preceding textview but now it is not tappable or its not recognizing the taps.

Main View has two subviews bodyView and navView:

[image]

bodyView has an imageView and two subviews(questionView and actionView):
questionView has a textview.

[image]

actionView has further two views leftView and RightView:

[image]

rightView has a button:

[image]

leftView has also two Views:
Userrelated and imageView

[image]

imageView has only one image called ProfileView:

[image]

userRelated view has a child view,the child view has a stackview as child and stack has a label and dropdown:

[image]

now the dropdown(which is in a stack which is further a subchild of 5th subchild of views) opens up on Post Msg Textfield(which is subchild of just 1 view)

Comment: Can you show the hierarchy of your views in your Storyboard? Or the layout? And have you tried adding a breakpoint to each IBActions or functions of your views? Perhaps indeed your tap is being sent to other views instead of that iOSDropDown.

Comment: In order to help, I think we will need more information about how you are placing textView and Dropdown view inside your parent view. Or share an example of your code.

Comment: ok thats my whole stroryboard hierarchy in images